# SymPy fails limit test

Tags: sympy

I am using the ratio test to find if the series with element `a = n**2/3**n` converges. On paper it is easy to see that the ratio a(n+1)/a(n) -> 1/3, but SymPy seem to fail in this test,

```
>>> n = symbols('n', integer=True)
>>> a = n**2/3**n
>>> a1 = a.subs(n, n+1)
>>> r = a1/a
>>> r
3**n*3**(-n - 1)*(n + 1)**2/n**2
>>> simplify(r)
(n + 1)**2/(3*n**2)
>>> expand(r)
1/3 + 2/(3*n) + 1/(3*n**2)
>>> limit(r, n, oo)
1
>>> limit(expand(r), n, oo)
1/3
```

Why can't SymPy evaluate the correct limit on the ratio a1/a ?

Comment: Looks like a bug in SymPy. I opened an issue for it https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/10610.

Comment: This is fixed in version 1.1.1